# How can I destructure object properties with key names that are invalid variable names?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

As object keys are strings, they can contain any kind of characters and special characters. I recently stumbled upon an object which I receive from an API call. This object has '-' in it's key names.

```
const object = {
   "key-with-dash": []
}
```

Destructuring does not work in this case, because `key-with-dash` is not a valid variable name.

```
const { key-with-dash } = object;
```

How am I supposed to destructure the object in such cases? Is it even possible at all?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```js
const data = {
   "key-with-dash": ["BAZ"]
}

const {"key-with-dash": foo} = data;

console.log("foo", foo);
```

Answer (score 51):

Just give it a valid name:

```js
let object = { 'key-with-dash': [] }
let {'key-with-dash':y} = object
console.log(y)
// => []
```

Or destructure using a variable:

```js
let object = { 'key-with-dash': [] }
let key = 'key-with-dash'
let {[key]:y} = object
console.log(y)
// => []
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip. Did not know about that :) Though I had to accept Hitmands answer as he was slightly faster :)

Comment: No justification necessary ^_^

Comment: Destructuring with variables is just what I needed!

Comment: This is really cool, absolutely horrific to read, but really cool nonetheless.

Answer (score -6):

I have found a breakthrough for this error if none of the previous answers work.

Follow this code:

```
const anyVar = yourData["data-example"]
```

Comment: The question is about destructuring, which that isn't.