# Trying to apply Ternary Operator on JSON Data with React

Tags: json, reactjs, conditional-operator

I am trying to apply a Ternary operator to some JSON Data which is held in a separate file locally.  Below is the JSON:

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "company": "Photosnap",
  "logo": "./images/photosnap.svg",
  "new": true,
  "featured": true,
  "position": "Senior Frontend Developer",
  "role": "Frontend",
  "level": "Senior",
  "postedAt": "1d ago",
  "contract": "Full Time",
  "location": "USA Only",
  "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "company": "Manage",
  "logo": "./images/manage.svg",
  "new": true,
  "featured": true,
  "position": "Fullstack Developer",
  "role": "Fullstack",
  "level": "Midweight",
  "postedAt": "1d ago",
  "contract": "Part Time",
  "location": "Remote",
  "languages": ["Python"],
  "tools": ["React"]
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "company": "Account",
  "logo": "./images/account.svg",
  "new": true,
  "featured": false,
  "position": "Junior Frontend Developer",
  "role": "Frontend",
  "level": "Junior",
  "postedAt": "2d ago",
  "contract": "Part Time",
  "location": "USA Only",
  "languages": ["JavaScript"],
  "tools": ["React"
```

Now the issue I have is I conditionally want to show a button dependent on whether "new" is true. [image: See Example] The same is said to be with the Featured button.
So I have written a Ternary Operator in my Component.

```
import React from 'react';

import './job-card.styles.css';

const JobCard = ({company, position, postedAt, contract, location, logo, featured, newJob })    => (

<div className="container">
   <div className='card'>
     <div className='companyName'>
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" width="100" height="100"></img>
    </div>
    <div className='content'>

        {{newJob} ? <button className='myButton'>New!</button> : null }
        {{featured} ? <button className='myDarkButton'>Featured</button> : null }
        <h2>{company}</h2>
        <h1>{position}</h1>
        <div className='details'>
            <h3>{postedAt} &#183;</h3>
            <h3>{contract} &#183;</h3>
            <h3>{location}</h3>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 )

 export default JobCard;
```

This is just a card component and feeds into another component which displays all the cards.

```
import React from 'react';

import './job-listing.styles.css';
import JobCard from '../job-card/job-card.component.jsx/job-card.component';
import { Component } from 'react';


class JobListing extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        jobs: []
    }
  };

 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({jobs: data}))

   }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.jobs.map(({id, ...otherJobProps}) =>(
            <JobCard key={id} {...otherJobProps} />
            ))}
        </div>
       )
     }
   }

  export default JobListing;
```

The output I am getting is that they are all rendering as true when some of the new or featured are false in the JSON Data. Not sure what I  have missed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `{newJob}` is an object, not a value. Even if `newJob` is `undefined`, you would have an object like `{newJob: undefined}` that evaluates as `true`, so renders the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the inner `{}`.

```js
{{newJob} ? <button className='myButton'>New!</button> : null }
// ^ here
```

Within JSX, `{}` denotes a javascript expression. But once you are within an expression, `{}` goes back to being normal object syntax. This is throwing off your ternary because you're checking whether an object with key `newJob` is truthy. Simply removing the brackets would fix it:

```js
{newJob ? <button className='myButton'>New!</button> : null }
```

---

**Regarding the `new` issue**

I prefer not to destructure props like this, but to get it working most like you already have, destructure the `new` reserved word into an alias. Here is a simple proof of concept:

```js
let test = [{ new: true }, { new: false }];

test.map(({new: isNew}) => console.log(isNew))
```

I would prefer to keep the data structured as is. But thats just a preference. It would also avoid the reserved word issue.

```js
let test = [{ new: true }, { new: false }];

test.map((value) => console.log(value.new))
```

Comment: Now it worked for featured but not for newJob as the property in JSON is new.  So I changed to new and now I get the following error ```Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'new'```

Comment: `new` is reserved, so you'll have to alias it when destructuring your props. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762715/how-to-destructure-object-properties-with-key-names-that-are-invalid-variable-na) for the `new` issue:

Comment: Basically you'll want to change your `map` to something like this: `map(({id, new: newJob,...otherJobProps})`

Comment: Thanks for your help Brian. Here is what I have done ``` { {new : newJob} ? <button className='myButton'>New!</button> : null }``` However this is not working for me.

Comment: No thats not what I meant. The change I suggested was for the `map` function inside `JobListing`, not for the ternary. The ternary will remain `{newJob ? //buton : null}`. Only change the `map`

Comment: So I have done this in the job-card component ```{ newJob ? <button className='myButton'>New!</button> : null }``` and this in the job-listing component ```{this.state.jobs.map(({id, new: newJob,...otherJobProps}) =>(
                <JobCard key={id} {...otherJobProps} />
                ))}```

Comment: Close. Just remember to also add `newJob` as a prop to `JobCard`. You could also do it in the definition of `JobCard`. As long as you rename the reserved word. But as you can see, this is why I prefer to just not destructure these types of things

Comment: The button does not appear. ```const JobCard = ({company, position, postedAt, contract, location, logo, featured, newJob }) => (
   
<div className="container">
    <div className='card'>
        <div className='companyName'>
            <img src={logo} alt="logo" width="100" height="100"></img>
        </div>
        <div className='content'>
        { newJob ? <button className='myButton'>New!</button> : null }
            
            {featured ? <button className='myDarkButton'>Featured</button> : null }
            ```

Comment: Try this instead.. `const JobCard = ({company, position, postedAt, contract, location, logo, featured, new: newJob }) => (`

Comment: Thank you! Life saver

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can simply do:

```
{newJob 
    && (<button className='myButton'>New!</button>)
}
{featured 
    && <button className='myDarkButton'>Featured</button>
}
```

It works because in JavaScript, `true && expression` always evaluates to expression,

and `false && expression` always evaluates to false.

Therefore, if the condition is `true`, the element right after `&&` will appear in the output. If it is `false`, React will ignore and skip it.

And `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""` are falsy values in JS.

---

[Ternary operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) is also an option if you really need two options (e.g):

```
<div>
    The user is <b>{isLoggedIn ? 'currently' : 'not'}</b> logged in.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the json objects I see the property `new: true` but the `JobCard` component receives `newJob` as part of it's props, not `new`.

To answer your question you see the buttons rendered because the condition `{newJob}` is an object which evaluates to true in:

```js
{{newJob} ? <button className='myButton'>New!</button> : null }
```

Why? Because `{newJob}` is the same as this: `{ newJob: newJob }` which is creating an object with a property called `newJob` and assigning it the value of `newJob` that you get from the component props.

What you want to do is one of the following:

```js
{newJob ? <button className='myButton'>New!</button> : null }
```

```js
{newJob && <button className='myButton'>New!</button> }
```