# How to destructure object properties with string key name

Tags: javascript, destructuring, object-destructuring

How to destructure this object:

```js
const game = {
    title: "YS",
    developer: "Falcom",
    releases: {
      "Oath In Felghana": ["USA", "Japan"],
      "Ark Of Napishtim": {
        US: "20 USD",
        JAP: "10 USD",
      },
      Origin: "30 USD",
    },
  };
```

so I can get (**"Oath In Felghana"**)the first key name of **releases** object in a variable.
I tried this but it didn't work

```js
 const{Object.keys(game.releases)[0]:keyName} = game
```

PS: I want to get the key Name (Oath In Felghana)

not the value ["USA", "Japan"]

Comment: If it was without spaces you could do it like this: `const { releases: { OathInFelghana } } = game`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to destructure object properties with key names that are invalid variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762715/how-to-destructure-object-properties-with-key-names-that-are-invalid-variable-na)

Comment: thank you
but no
I want to store the key name not the value

Comment: `const [ game ] = Object.keys(game.releases);`

Comment: s there any other way to do it ? because I want to destructure all object properties in a single destructuring Assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the key name as follows:

```
const [ keyName ] = Object.keys(game.releases);
```

Comment: this will store the value ["USA", "Japan"]
I want to store the key name "Oath In Felghana"

Answer (score 2):

From the above comments ...

> *`const [ game ] = Object.keys(game.releases);`* – Peter Seliger
>
> > *[I]s there any other way to do it ? because I want to destructure all object properties in a single destructuring Assignment.* – B-M Amine

In case the OP wants to separate all game name related entries of `game.releases` from the non related `Origin` property, the OP needs to utilize the [object destructuring ***rest property***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property)

```js
const game = {
  title: "YS",
  developer: "Falcom",
  releases: {
    "Oath In Felghana": ["USA", "Japan"],
    "Ark Of Napishtim": {
      US: "20 USD",
      JAP: "10 USD",
    },
    Origin: "30 USD",
  },
};
const [ firstGameName ] = Object.keys(game.releases);

console.log({ firstGameName });

// OP ... [I]s there any other way to do it ?
//        because I want to destructure all
//        object properties in a single
//        destructuring Assignment.

const allGameNames = Object
  .keys(
    // rest property as of object destructuring ...
    // ... see [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property]
    (({ Origin, ...releaseEntries }) => releaseEntries)(game.releases)
  );
console.log({ allGameNames });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/c0ne2Lrv/8/

you will find the answer here.

```
const game = {
  title: "YS",
  developer: "Falcom",
  releases: {
    "Oath In Felghana": ["USA", "Japan"],
    "Ark Of Napishtim": {
      US: "20 USD",
      JAP: "10 USD",
    },
    Origin: "30 USD",
  },
};

({
  title: t,
  developer: d,
  releases:  {
    "Oath In Felghana":[u,j],
    "Ark Of Napishtim":{US:u_price, JAP:j_price},
    Origin:or
  }
} = game);

[o,a,] = Object.keys(game.releases);




// Write Your Destructuring Assignment/s Here

console.log(`My Favourite Games Style Is ${t} Style`);
// My Favourite Games Style Is YS Style

console.log(`And I Love ${d} Games`);
// And I Love Falcom Games

console.log(`My Best Release Is ${o} It Released in ${u} and ${j}`);
// My Best Release Is Oath In Felghana It Released in USA & Japan

console.log(`Although I Love ${a}`);
// Although I Love Ark Of Napishtim

console.log(`${a} Price in USA Is ${u_price}`);
// Ark Of Napishtim Price in USA Is 20 USD

console.log(`${a} Price in Japan Is ${j_price}`);
// Ark Of Napishtim Price in Japan Is 10 USD

console.log(`Origin Price Is ${or}`);
// Origin Price Is 30 USD
```